# knock out foreach binding with independent varriable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using `knockout` for binding in my html5 application.

I have one strange scenario.

One div i am binding using for loop like below

> ```
> <div data-bind="foreach: oneList">
> <select name="dropDown1" id="dropDown1" data-bind="options: ddList,optionsText: function(item) { return item.value;},optionsValue:function(item) { return item.key; }">
> </select>
> <input type="text" id="newValue" data-bind="value : oneValue"/>
> </div>
> ```

Here `oneList` is diffent varriable and `ddList` is a diffent varriable,both are independent varriable.

So when actual binding happens drop down does not get binded but input text is binded because `oneList.oneValue` is valid but `oneList.ddList` is not valid

Please let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: do you really have your `input` **inside** the `select` element? Because this does not valid HTML and it could confuse the KO bindings...

Comment: sorry it was just copy/paste issue actually it is outside select element.Please check updated question.

Comment: fist you should check your browser's console for binding errors. Then you should also post your view model because without it we cannot tell why the bindings are not working. Propbably there is no `oneList.ddList` and you need to "go up" in the binding context with the use `$parent` or `$root` e.g `data-bind="options: $parent.ddList...`

Comment: Thanks @nemesv It is working please post you answer i will accept and close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your view-model it is quite hard to tell, but most probably there is no `ddList` property defined on items in the `oneList` list.

Inside a `foreach` binding the current binding context refers to the current item from the list so if you need to "go up" in the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) to access a property which is on the same level as your `onlist`  then you need to use `$parent` (or `$root` to access your main view-model).

A fixed `options` binding would look like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.ddList, optionsText:...  " >
```